# IE8/IE7 cause me an error on a jquery call

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

This bug appear only in my IE8 and IE7. When I do

```
$("div").css("opacity", "0");
```

The browser cause an error:

Could not get the display property. Invalid argument.

**Note**: my jquery version come from a download of the site at 2:30 PM today.

**Note2** : I have tried to do:

```
$("div").css("display", "none");
```

but it does not work at all.

**Note 3**: The mention code work on all other browser.

EDIT:
For comprehension pupose this is the complete code:

```
        if ($.cookie('splashWindow') == null) {
            if (!$.browser.msie || ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == "9.0")) {
                $("div").css("opacity", "0");
                $("#firstLineWrapper").css("opacity", "1");
                $("#firstMenu").css("opacity", "0");
                $("#wrapper, #ctl00_logo, #header, #header .BannerSection, #header .BannerSection #slideshow").delay(500).animate({ "opacity": "1" }, 1500, function () { $("div, #firstMenu").delay(500).animate({ "opacity": "1" }, 2000); });
            } else {
                $("div").hide();
                //$("#firstLineWrapper").css("display", "none");
                //$("#firstMenu").css("display", "none");
                //$("#wrapper, #ctl00_logo, #header, #header .BannerSection, #header .BannerSection #slideshow").delay(500).animate({ "display": "block" }, 1500, function () { $("div, #firstMenu").delay(500).animate({ "display": "block" }, 2000); });
            }
            $.cookie('splashWindow', 'cookieValue', { expires: 0.5 });
        }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

IE does not support opacity. Strange, I know, but it doesn't. All other browsers do, which is why you don't have a problem there. You can try jQuery's `.hide()` method. Or if you want to get fancy, you could try the `.fadeOut()` method. jQuery will compensate for IE's holes and it will work if you do it that way.

Hope that helps,
spryno724

Comment: Dam! This solution does not work. I got the same error at the same place.

Comment: Hmm... I have used this in the past, and it has worked well. Try this example: `$('div').fadeTo(1000, 0)`.

Comment: The only thing I could guess is either that the selector is making too broad of a selection (too many DIVs), or you have another AJAX library conflicting some where, even if it is another version of jQuery. Try giving the DIV and class name or an ID, then use that to select it.

Comment: My probleme is even their when I specify the div to hide ( $("#firstMenu").hide(); )

Comment: Great news, By removing some hold code from my javascript, that was execute at the same time (on document ready) but in a ohter file, the problem is solved.

Comment: @spryno724: IE supports native opacity from V9 and versions beyond may use opacity too because jQuery has a cssHook included for browsers that not support opacity.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but since Muffun was referring to IE7 and 8, I guess I just answered specifically for those versions. I hadn't heard about the cssHook, though, good to know.